# Creating an uberjar for a project that uses MySQL and SQLServer

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to build a project in clojure that takes data from a
Microsoft SQL Server database, and pushes it to a MySQL database.

The project runs fine using lein run, but when I package it into an
uberjar using leiningen, and run it using java -jar, it fails with:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: 
>   No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver....

This error only happens when I attempt to use both the MySQL database and
the SQL Server database. If I use any one of them on its own, the jar file 
runs fine using java -jar.

My project.clj is as follows:

```
(defproject sqlserver-clojure "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "A minimal example of the MySQL/SQLServer conflict"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
             [com.microsoft/sqljdbc4 "3.0"]
             [clojureql "1.0.4"]
             [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.6"]]
  :main sqlserverclojure.core)
```

Comment: Uber-jars are evil; you probably don't copy certain resources or entries in `META-INF`, or worse overwriting them (eg `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` exists in all JDBC 4 compliant drivers with different content)

Comment: You could always fall back to the "classic" method of loading JDBC drivers, using `Class.forName("driver.class.Name")` somewhere in your application before using JDBC. Alternately you could use `DataSource` objects instead of `DriverManager.getConnection()`

Comment: @millimoose Mentioning of `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` was just an example, the loading of the driver could still fail (even when using the classic method or a `DataSource`), for example because other required resources weren't copied

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Interesting...there is indeed a META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver in the jar package and it only contains an entry for the MySQL driver. Is there an alternative to using an uberjar here? What would you recommend?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It might fail, and it might not, I don't really believe it's all that common in practice to put anything under `META-INF/` that could have filename conflicts besides the relatively few features of the JDK that make use of that information. And beyond that "something else might fail" comes across as FUD-spreading.

Comment: @millimoose I have seen examples were making an uber-jar failed to copy resources (eg property files, XML config etc) which then caused a failure in the loading of classes that depended on the presence of those files.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm not saying it's not a valid concern, I'm just not sure it's enough to drop the uberjar approach which certainly makes deployment easier. (Also, ["shading"](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) would help with some resource conflicts.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is most likely that when making the uber-jar, you are not copying some files (eg `.properties` or XML config) that are required by the driver, or you are overwriting files that exist in both JDBC drivers.

A good example of overwriting is the `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file which all JDBC 4 drivers have. This file contains a list of all classes in the jar implementing `java.sql.Driver`, so that the `java.sqlDriverManager` class can automatically load all Driver implementations using [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

If you create an uber-jar with multiple JDBC drivers, you either need to make sure this file contains the union of all these files, or your application needs to explicitly load the drivers you need with `Class.forName("<name of the java.sql.Driver implementation>")` for each required driver and not depend on the JDBC 4 driver autoloading.

Also verify that the process you use to create the uber-jar copies **all resources** and not just `.class` files!

Better yet (in my opinion), don't use an uber-jar, but keep the dependent `.jar` files external and reference them in the `Class-Path` entry of the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file of your application, this saves you a lot of hassle to get your uber-jar working correctly (or verify that it is actually working correctly).

Comment: Great explanation... but do you have any idea if that is possible to correct in future versions of lein?  (is it even possible to fix?)

Comment: @joefromct The simplest solution is to not create an uber-jar, but reference the required libraries in the manifest. I do not know if there are solutions that address all these concerns when merging libraries into one jar because I never do that myself. Technically it would be possible to address most of these problems of merging, except maybe config files with same names that can't be merged.

Comment: This answer saved my life. Class.forName() addition solved the problem.  Class.forName() by the way  is not thread safe, if you are creating  connections from different JDBC drivers by multithreading for performance reasons, just don't.

Comment: @MertSerimer `Class.forName` for loading drivers should be thread-safe, but I know there are some JDBC drivers doing odd things while being loaded that could cause a deadlock. If you run into such a problem, consider filing a bug report with the maintainer/vendor of the driver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yeah i had that deadlock issue you mentioned, so it is not being thread-safe but rather what you said hmmm.. Thanks again anyway..

Answer (score 1):

Adding this for my own reference since I've not touched Java before and struggle with Java interop.

Add

```
(. Class (forName "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"))
```

In the namespace with your jdbc clojure function calls.